# AVR ATMEGA32A UART not send and receive data unless programmer is connected

Tags: avr, uart, atmega, adapter, programmer

The code in micro is to turn a LED on when it receives "1" from UART and off when receives "0".
For VCC I use a phone adapter  (5V, 0.7A) which works properly and is suitable for micro.
However data is not transmitted between my laptop and micro properly unless in addition to adapter, micro is also connected to laptop via programmer.

I need to know what is the possible problems 'cause the rest of my project is done!

Comment: Are there any differences in data connections for DTR, DSR   Etc? For the PC to recognize that the UART is connected?

Comment: Did you forget maybe ground connection that the programmer provides, and without it RXD and TXD don't work?

Answer (score 1):

In general this sort of thing is often because the compilation is for debug and the processor is trying to communicate with the debugger.

Or, more simply, you might not have dealt properly with the MCU reset input. The programmer will drive the reset input.